# Xcode 12 provided sqlite3 implementation of sqlite3_column_type returns always deprecated SQLITE_ANY data type

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite

The database definition:

```
 % sqlite3 test.db 
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-15 14:49:49
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select * from stest;
1974|19.74|Hallo Welt|
sqlite> .schema stest
CREATE TABLE stest (int_test integer, real_test real, text_test text, blob_test blob);
sqlite> select int_test,real_test,text_test from stest;
1974|19.74|Hallo Welt
sqlite> select typeof(int_test) from stest;
integer
sqlite> select typeof(real_test) from stest;
real
sqlite> select typeof(text_test) from stest;
text
sqlite>
```

I prepare the simple sql select * from stest and try to get the column type:

```
  rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select" + _sql, -1, &ppStmt, &pzTail);
...
  if columnCount > 0 {
                    
                    for cc in 0..<columnCount {
                        
                        let ct = sqlite3_column_type(ppStmt, cc);
                        columnTypeArray.append(ct);
...
```

The loop runs three times for each of the column but the variable ct contains always the data type SQLITE_ANY:

[image]

Inside the definition provided by Xcode SQLITE_ANY is signed as deprecated:

[image]

So what's wrong in my code? Why I did't got the correct requested data type?

Comment: That's not a value that (the C) `sqlite3_column_type()` is documented as returning. You are calling `sqlite3_step()` first on the prepared statement (or whatever the equivalent is in swift), right?

Comment: Yes I do, in  the meanwhile I switched to use sqlite_column_decltype and evaluate the strings the function returns. That seems to work for original types, all others will be returned a VARIANT.